# Soundtrack ID: Christopher Robin Official Trailer

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I found the soundtrack at the ending of the trailer of *Christopher Robin* (2018) very uplifting and energetic. But Shazam does not recognize this song. Can anybody help me identify it?

The soundtrack is playing from 2:03s in the trailer: https://youtu.be/0URpDxIjZrQ?t=2m3s

Comment: Well, the music credit is [Jon Brion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Brion), but it may just be a filler piece of music rather than an actual song. Guess more information will be out when the film is out in August

Comment: @Angst Wow! Where can I get the credit info about the melody (since it may simply be a piece of music specially written for the trailer)? Anyway, about the point on the release of the whole soundtrack album, I do think it may help clear out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a remix of "Follow the Sun" by The Lighthouse and the Whaler.

The [band's website](http://www.thelighthouseandthewhaler.com/) describes them as the artists behind the song, but the version in the trailer is actually

> The Hit House’s orchestral remix, by composer William August Hunt
>   http://www.thehithouse.com/what-to-do-with-winnie-the-pooh/

I can't find the actual song on Spotify or the website. Hopefully the movie soundtrack will have it!

---

**Update:** [Zync Music claims](https://www.zyncmusic.com/#/the-lighthouse-and-the-whaler-christopher-robin/) that they helped with the licensing of this placement in the trailer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! It seems really magical to me that you found the post by the Hit House! Hopefully they will include it in the score.

Answer (score 0):

The song you are looking for is Walk the Moon- One Foot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05v4nfUmBYI

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, *One Foot* is featured in the *Adventure* featurette of the film (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anKVhZU7D1s), but not the one I am asking here. Hopefully it will come with the film soundtrack.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is it? I was looking for it too.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7BWUI3fVkGs

Comment: I wish this is. But apparently, the #2 trailer does not use *One Foot* by Walk the Moon. I believe James' answer is the right one to the question. Let's wish *Follow the Sun* would show up in the soundtrack!

Answer (score 0):

The song is brilliantine of audiomachine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dK6wNz8_gmo

Answer (score -1):

Hello so I took a look at the trailer and instantly recognized the song at the beginning.... I hope I can help you out. I spent hours trying to remember its name but I got it:

["Remember Not to Forget"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4M2rDHGE1cs) by Audiomachine.

Hope this help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! But I feel like the soundtrack starting at 2:03, which I am looking for, is another one.